# connecting sql server using amazon web services to python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I want to access the **sql** server using the amazon web services. How do I do it? I have tried this using mysql.connecter in python.

```
import mysql.connecter
conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="hostname",database="datbasename",user="root",password="a")
if conn.is_connected():
    print('connected to mysql database')
```

Comment: Maybe share the error you're having?.. And what is SQL server in AWS? Is it RDS? EC2?

Comment: its ec2.where do i get the host name ,database name and all..

Comment: Well, you configure the db name. The hostname will be the EC2 instance IP address.

Comment: Thanks sir , but please can u help me on what must the host name and password must be...i have searched this a lot but didn't get anything ....Thanks.

Comment: You should have configured them yourself, or they are the default SQL server ones. I dont know which, but I definitely cant just 'tell you' them